# How do I find and delete duplicate values in a range of cells while keeping the first occurrence of a duplicated value in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

Ideally, I want to be able to search through an entire sheet (or range of cells) and remove any values that have been repeated in that sheet (for example, if "**2**" appears in `A3`, `B8`, and `D4`, then I want to keep it in `A3` and delete it in `B8` and `D4`).

I normally see this problem addressed by looking at one column or row for duplicates (using the `UNIQUE` function) but not for an entire sheet.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some code that will do that for an entire sheet.

*Please note it will work on text and numbers and it will overwrite any formulas.*

```
function removeDuplicates() {

    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
    var range = sheet.getDataRange();
    var values = range.getValues();

    var traversedValues = [];

    var rowCount = values.length;
    var colCount = values[0].length;

    for (var row = 0; row < rowCount; ++row) {

        for (var col = 0; col < colCount; ++col) {

            var value = values[row][col];

            if (traversedValues.indexOf(value) > -1) {
                values[row][col] = null;
            } else {
                traversedValues.push(value);
            }
        }
    }

    range.setValues(values);
}
```

---

#### References for you

[Beginner's guide to coding with Google Apps Script](https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/starting-gas/)

[For loops](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)

[`if...else` statements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else)

[Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)